# ROUTE53 Failover from ALB to ALB not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-application-load-balancer

I want route53 to failover from ALB1 to ALB2.

I've set up a DNS hosted zone, using ALB FQDN, set up Alias record for ALB1, set failover routing policy, based on a health check using ALB1 endpoint FQDN, also set up Alias record for ALB2 as secondary.

Each ALB has a target group of two ec2 running simple apache website.

ALB1 has two ec2, I tried shutting them, and/or turning httpd, to simulate failed health check and each time this happens, I get bad gateway error message.  It doesn't seem to want to failover to ALB2.

[image: hosted zone records and primary alias record]
[image: hosted zone records and secondary alias record]
[image: route53 health check]

What am I doing wrong/incorrectly or don't understand?  My goal is to simulate a failover.

Please advise.

Comment: @Marcin I ended up not pursuing route53 solution and used a single ALB with a single target group comprised of two active ec2 and two passive ec2.  Also created a lambda function to launch passive ec2, once cloudwatch http5xxx alarm triggers it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have your **own domain**. You can't re-define AWS owned domain that is provided to you by your ALB. Then you create the R53 fail-over records for your own domain, e.g. `myapp.org`.